# Databound Listbox not updating?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, listbox

I have a Listbox which is to display a list of product names which it reads from a database table, bound using the inbuild datasource/databinding stuff..however when the product names are updated/more are added in the table etc no change is reflected in the Listbox! only the initial names from when it was first bound appear, how to fix this?

I have been searching for a while but found no solution which works for me, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: ASP.Net or Winforms? It would also help if you would show us some code.

Comment: there's not really any code to show relative to this..atleast i don't think there is, there's this auto generated piece from using the databinding on the listbox:

'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'SystemDbDataSet.ProductTbl' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.ProductTblTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SystemDbDataSet.ProductTbl)

Comment: ...and the answer on my first question is?

Comment: oh i updated it in the title, WinForms yeah

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a timer control to refresh and fill the ListBox every 30 seconds or so.

Other than that you could also setup the ListBox to update OnClick or OnSelectedIndexChange -both solutions would be a little tricky and would involve keeping the same selection even if th ListBox.Items have grown by say 10 items.